# Is there a way to retrieve objects with nested Lists via Spring's restTemplate

Tags: java, spring, resttemplate

This is the object we are trying to retrieve:

```
// Lombok annotated
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString(callSuper = true)
public class GetTransactionsResponse  {

  public String name;

  public List<Transaction> list;
}
```

We have an object that has metadata and a list of objects

We tried using spring's restTemplate in a method like the following:

```
public GetTransactionsResponse getTransactions(String token, Request request) {
    var requestEntity = RequestEntity
      .get(externalApiClient.getTransactionsPath())
      .header(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, token)
      .build();

    return handleCall(requestEntity, GetTransactionsResponse.class);
}

private <T> T handleCall(RequestEntity<?> requestEntity, Class<T> clazz) {
  try {
    var result = restTemplate.exchange(requestEntity, clazz).getBody();
    log.info("method: handleCall - requestEntity: {} - clazz: {} - result: {}", requestEntity, clazz, result);
    return result;
  } catch (Exception e) {
    throw e
  } 
}
```

So we call the rest template but we are receiving null. Without nested data the previous method works but somehow returns `null` when using nested objects. Are we using rest template wrong?

Comment: How are you calling handleSvcCall method? Also you should return value without calling getBody

Comment: It will just work, if it doesn't you are like don't have getters/setters (not sure what part of Lombok you are using) or the name doesn't match the JSON you are receiving.

Answer (score 0):

First verify that your Rest API you created actually works. Test it with posman or ARC (Advanced Rest Client) - a plugin for chrome and see that you get the desired result. If it works, then you can send request to your API from any Http Client including Rest Template. If your API works but calling it from Rest Template doesn't then you will know that the problem is on your client side and you can try and figure out why. But first verify that your Rest API actually works and not returning null

Comment: Hello our API works; it just doesn't seem to map onto the objects from our client code

Comment: Are you running your Rest Template from Spring context where your entities are all visible?

Comment: Is there a way to know that?

Comment: If you run your rest template from the server side where your entity classes can be used...

Comment: Yes, this is what we are doing